# What is the alternative for while(0) or while(1) in Java?

Tags: java, c, bit-manipulation

I am solving an interview question which is to write a method that does the addition of two digits without using the + operator.

I understand the algorithm very well and I can do it easily in C.

Here is the algorithm and it works perfectly:

```
int add(int x, int y) {
int a, b;
do {
    a = x & y;           
    b = x ^ y; 
    x = a << 1; 
    y = b;
} while (a);
  return b;
}
```

I tried translating this code to Java, but this algorithm functions because a is going to become 000 at one point which in C will equal to False in the while loop. What is the alternative for that in Java?

Thanks.

Comment: `while (x != 0)` or `while (x != 1)`

Comment: In java you can't use `int`s for conditions. You must use `boolean`. `while(boolean)` like `while(a==b)`, `while(true)`, etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a boolean for the condition in Java:

`while (a != 0)`

Edit (full code):

```
int add(int x, int y) {
int a, b;
do {
    a = x & y;           
    b = x ^ y; 
    x = a << 1; 
    y = b;
} while (a != 0);
return b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java does not - unlike C - interprete `0` as `false`. As stated in my comment you have to use a boolean expression such as:

```
while (a != 0)
```